# How to convert a piece of CSS code to LESS css

Tags: html, css, less

I am using LESS css in my code. But i am not able to write this in LESS.

```
.A .B div.span4 a, .A .B div.span12 a, .A .B div.span6 a 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3b5998;
    color: @white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: @font-size-base;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any compilation errors?

Comment: No, I am asking about how to nest these classes.

Comment: Oh I see. The `.A .B div.` part is common for all three selectors in your code and so you can start nesting them like `.A .B div{
&.span4 a, &.span12 a, &.span6 a {/*settings*/} }` for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a Windows user you can use 3rd party softwares like Winless. Also there are some online tools such as [Css2less](http://css2less.cc/), [Lessify](http://leafo.net/lessphp/lessify/)

Comment: I am using mac book. Css2less is not showing result. I have already checked.

Comment: try using one of these tools http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/internet-roundup/5-mac-apps-that-make-css-preprocessors-easier-to-use/

Comment: Thank-you. Lessify worked for me..A {.B {div.span4 a,  div.span12 a, div.span6 a 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3b5998;
    color: @white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: @font-size-base;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}}} This is the way

Answer (score 2):

More optimized:

```
.A .B 
{
  div.span4,
  div.span12,
  div.span6
  {
    a 
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3b5998;
        color: @white;
        display: block;
        font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
        font-size: @font-size-base;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
  }
}
```